# ¿Cómo obtener el valor de un input text en tiempo real usando Angular?

Tags: angular

Quiero mostrar un botón hasta detectar que se escribió algo en el input.

```
<div class="editar-contenedor" *ngIf="mostrarEdicion[i]">
  <input
      type="text"
      *ngIf="mostrarEdicion[i]"
      placeholder="Descripción de la imagen"
      #descripcion>
  <div class="row">
    <h1>{{descripcion}}</h1>
    <div class="col" ngIf="descripcion.value != ''">
      <button
          type="button"
          name="button"
          class="boton-galeria-imagen-individual btn btn-success btn-block"
          (click)="mostrarEdicionCaja(i)">
        Guardar Cambios
      </button>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <button
          type="button"
          name="button"
          class="boton-galeria-imagen-individual btn btn-danger btn-block"
          (click)="mostrarConfirmacionEliminar(i)">
        Cancelar
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Pero no puedo obtener el valor del input con

```
<h1>{{descripcion}}</h1>
<div class="col" ngIf="descripcion.value != ''">
```

Comment: Intenta cambiando ngIf por ngShow y tambien la expresion `description.value != ''` por `description.length > 0` y dime que pasa.

Answer (score 1):

No entendí muy claramente tu respuesta, pero lo que puedes hacer es usar el doble data biding en el input y para ocultar o esconder el botón puedes usar el length de la variable bindeada si es mayor que 0 significa que se escribió en el input, te pongo un ejemplo muy básico, tal vez puedas adaptarlo a tu codigo https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ed6wzm?file=app%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: El link de ejemplo ya no esta disponible

Answer (score 1):

Una manera simple de resolver esto puede ser con `[(ngModel)]` y `*ngIf`

Tu input iría de esta manera:

```html
<input [(ngModel)]='textoDeInput' 
type="text" 
class="form-control" 
placeholder="" 
aria-label="" 
aria-describedby="basic-addon1">
```

Y en tu componente:

```js
textoDeInput: string = null
```

El botón seria así:

```
<button  *ngIf='textoDeInput' class="btn btn-outline-secondary" type="button">Aqui toy</button>
```

Para mi lo correcto es que lo hagas a a través de reactive forms y obtengas las validaciones.

Este es un código de ejemplo en [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-34bvjn) sobre lo que quieres.

Este es un [ejemplo con validaciones](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7-reactive-form-validation)

Y un poco de información sobre [reactive forms](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms) y sus [validaciones](https://angular.io/guide/form-validation#reactive-form-validation)

Comment: Compañero muchas gracias... me sirvio tu ejemplo.